# Cannot find ubuntu in windows default os list. How can i get that in list?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, hp

I installed Ubuntu on an HP ProBook 450 G7 laptop. I tried to modify startup and recovery. In the OS list, I don't find Ubuntu.

[image: screenshot of startup and recovery]

How can I get Ubuntu into this list?
(Note: I want Windows as my default OS)

Answer (score 1):

The Windows bootloader doesn't support booting Linux. So you  need to install different bootloader like GRUB (during Ubuntu installation, or booting into Ubuntu using your installation CD or USB and installing GRUB). GRUB (and other "linux" bootloaders) allows you to configure to make your Windows a default boot option.

Installing and configuring GRUB on existing installations it too broad topic. If you are not experienced Linux user, reinstalling Ubuntu would be the simplest option. During install pay attention to those steps related to bootloader and don't skip them.